# Should I repot my birds of paradise?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, repotting

I just got this birds of paradise from someone and just noticed that the root is growing out of the drainage hole. It's not blocking the entire hole but I'm wondering if I have to repot this since the leaves look a little droopy and no matter how much I've been watering it, it doesn't seem to fully perk up. The pot is a 12in size planter so it seems large enough for this plant so if yes I should repot this, could I reuse the same planter but add more soil and move the plant up a little more since the soil doesn't fill all the way up to the top? Or, should I be getting a bigger sized planter and repotting the entire thing there. For reference, the tallest leaf is only 29inches above the planter.

Below are some pictures of my plants.

[image: picture of the roots coming out of the pot]

[image: picture of the roots in the current pot]

[image: full picture of the entire plant]

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely to not be getting enough light and being overwatered. Repotting will only stress the plant. I recommend:

- cut the root coming out of the pot off as it leaves the pot
- move right next to a south or west window with no blinds or curtains
- water only when the top inch of the soil is dry
- when you do water: add enough so it runs out of the bottom of the pot

Comment: Well said. Moving the curtain away and bringing the pot to the window will make a difference. More sun.